# Summing R, G, and B Channels

Tags: python, image, opencv, rgb

Given,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('./my_img.jpg')
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
```

I am confused why I get different values for

```
im_sum = r + g + b
```

versus

```
im_sum2 = np.sum(img, axis=2)
```

If I write

```
h, w = img.shape[:2]

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        if im_sum[i,j] != im_sum2[i,j]:
            print(im_sum[i,j] - im_sum2[i,j])
```

I get a whole bunch of print outs of

```
4294967040
```

Which is actually equal to

```
2**32 - 256
```

Can anyone enlighten me on this? Does it have something to do with uint32 vs. uint8 images?

Comment: `r + g + b` where all 3 arrays have datatype of `uint8` also produces a `uint8` result (so values overflow during the add). `np.sum` produces an array with datatype `uint32`, hence no overflow happens here. i.e. the first case is equivalent to `np.sum(img, axis=2) % 256`

Comment: you can verify using `type(im_sum[i,j])` vs `type(im_sum2[i,j])`.  As for `2**32-256`, that's also the 2's complement representation of `-256`. so the `int32` version is probably `unsigned int32`

Comment: @Masek Yes, you're right. If I compare dtype's, I get im_sum is uint8 and im_sum2 is uint32.

How do I credit you with answer?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b You're right as well.

Comment: One last thing, for those who read this. If you are attempting to create an rg chromaticity image, you have to let im_sum (in this example) be int32. int8 only goes up to 256, but the sum of 3 channels can go all the way up o 3*255. The division will automatically convert, so don't worry. In fact, you want to do something like `np.ma.divide(1.*r, im_sum) ` for the r-channel (e.g.) to avoid integer division flooring to 0.